# Parent scope of angular directive not updating UI

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/3jos4pLb/

My problem is you can see my directive is communicating with my parent controller scope by setting the finalValue, however when the window resize is triggered the scope.finalValue gets updated by viewing the console.log however the UI does not reflect this update.  I am trying to be able to have this keep getting updated on window resizing.  In other words, the directive successfully passes the scope.finalValue to parent controller on first load overriding the set value of 5 (the new value is the height of the window).  However as i resize although i see in the console the scope.finalValue changing values, the UI is not updating.

```
var app=angular.module('App', []);

app.controller("Ctrl1", function($scope){
    $scope.finalValue = 5;
});
app.directive('elheightresize', ['$window', function($window) {
    return {
    restrict: "EA",
    scope: false,
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            scope.onResize = function() {
                    scope.finalValue = $window.innerHeight;
                console.log(scope.finalValue);
               // var header = document.getElementsByTagName('header')[0];
               // elem.windowHeight = $window.innerHeight - header.clientHeight;
               // $(elem).height(elem.windowHeight);
            }
            scope.onResize();

            angular.element($window).bind('resize', function() {
                scope.onResize();
            })
        }
    }
}])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using jql to bind the resize event.  jql is very low-level, and directly binds the handler function to the element, bypassing normal angular dirty-checking.  In order to make angular aware of non-angular event handlers, you need to call scope.$apply() in your event handler, to let angular know it needs to run a digest cycle.